# How to check if a control is resigning first responder or become first responder?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextfield, delegatecommand, resignfirstresponder

I have a view that a content some NSTextfields and NSComboboxes. I want to do something when one of these controls resign first responder. I already try the delegate method

```
- (BOOL)control:(NSControl *)control textShouldEndEditing:(NSText *)fieldEditor
      if ([control isKindOfClass: [NSTextField class]]){
          //custom code
          return YES;
      }
}
```

but it requires that i do something in the previous field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something *resignFirstResponder* instead of *textShouldEndEditing*

Comment: I didn't know about this delegate

Comment: It's not a delegate. It's a method that your controls are inheriting from `NSResponder`. Sounds like you need to read up about the [Cocoa events system.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i)

Answer (score 1):

You can ask the corresponding UIView e.g. with

[view isFirstResponder]